# Play Framework 2.5 Serializing JSON Traits

Tags: json, playframework

I have a sealed trait that is like below:

```
sealed trait MyMessages

object MyMessages {

  case object Init extends MyMessages
  case object Destroy extends MyMessages
  case class Tick(elem: Long) extends MyMessages
}
```

I have to now write a formatter for serializing and de-serializing this into to and from a JSON. This is what I came up with:

```
  implicit object MyMessagesWrites extends Writes[MyMessages] {
    def writes(myMessages: MyMessages): JsValue = myMessages match {
      case Init => Json.toJson("INIT")
      case Destroy => Json.toJson("DESTROY")
      case tick: Tick => Json.toJson(Tick)
    }

    def reads(json: JsValue): MyMessages = {
      // How do I get from JSValue to a MyMessages type???
    }
  }
```

Implementing the writes was easy, but how do I implement the reads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you serialize the `Tick` instance as a bare JSON number, I would do it like so:

```
implicit object MyMessageReads extends Reads[MyMessages] {
  def reads(json: JsValue) = json match {
    case JsString("INIT") => JsSuccess(MyMessages.Init)
    case JsString("DESTROY") => JsSuccess(MyMessages.Destroy)
    case JsNumber(n) => JsSuccess(Tick(n.toLongExact))
    case e => JsError(s"Invalid message: $e")
  }
}
```

Note that you can also make the reads/writes a bit more succinct by using the more functional style:

```
implicit val myMessagesWrites = Writes[MyMessages] {
  case Init => JsString("INIT")
  case Destroy => JsString("DESTROY")
  case Tick(n) => JsNumber(n)
}

implicit val myMessageReads = Reads[MyMessages] {
  case JsString("INIT") => JsSuccess(MyMessages.Init)
  case JsString("DESTROY") => JsSuccess(MyMessages.Destroy)
  case JsNumber(n) => JsSuccess(Tick(n.toLongExact))
  case e => JsError(s"Invalid message: $e")
}
```